# How can I reduce the white space around the title and the author in beamer?

Tags: beamer, titles, beamerposter, posters, author

I am creating an academic poster in beamer, but there is way too much whitespace above the title and below the author sections.
[image: Lots of whitespace]

I added \vspace to my title command, but negative values simply cut off the bottom of the title. Below is -1cm.

[image: negative cm]

```
\documentclass[final,t, xcolor=dvipnames]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Berlin}}

\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=a0,scale=1,debug]{beamerposter}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\FontBody{\fontsize{24pt}{28pt}\selectfont}
\newcommand\FontHead{\fontsize{32pt}{28pt}\selectfont}

\title[]{\vspace{1cm}\Huge Molecular Dynamics \textit{in silico} Modelling Simulations Using Amber Software Tools}
\logo{%
    \makebox[1\paperwidth]{%
    \includegraphics[width=15cm, height=15cm, keepaspectratio]{./pictures/logo1.png}
    \hfill%
    \includegraphics[width=12cm, height=12cm, keepaspectratio]{./pictures/logo2.png}
    }%
}
\author[]{\Large \textbf{Author Name}}
\institute[]{\Large The University of Somewhere}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\maketitle
\begin{columns}[T]
\begin{column}{.3\linewidth}

\FontHead
\begin{block}{\textbf{Background}}
```

Comment: The argument of `\title` should *never* contain commands like `\Huge` of `\vspace`. I guess you want `\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\Huge}`.

Comment: Thank you Campa, I have updated my code, however this didn't fix my white-space issue. Could you explain why I should avoid those commands in my title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I managed to solve this with a little \vspace{} experimentation

**For the title**

I deleted all commands from the title line and added a \setbeamerfont variable (as suggested by Campa above). Then I added a \vspace{} command after the initial frame command (I assume this moved the whole frame upwards, eliminating the top whitespace.

```
\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\Huge}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]\vsapce{-6cm}
\maketitle
```

**For the columns**

For each column, I added a /vspace command on the \begin column line. I had to do this for each column. Using the command at the beginning of the columns block didn't seem to work. E.g.)

```
\begin{columns}[T]
\begin{column}{.3\linewidth}\vspace{-6cm}
```

Hopefully this helps anyone having similar issues.